# Which is the correct output for std::is_pod for this code

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Three different compilers do not all agree with the result of the STL's `std::is_pod` test

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyPODObject
{
    MyPODObject() = delete;
    int value;
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "MyPODObject is POD: " << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<MyPODObject>::value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**VS2022**

```
MyPODObject is POD: false
```

**GCC 12**

```
MyPODObject is POD: true
```

**CLang 15**

```
MyPODObject is POD: false
```

What is the expected result?
From my research so far, I was expecting to see `false`.

**Results so far:**
On Windows, clang says `false`
On Linux, clang says `true`

Comment: Just a note: `is_pod` is deprecated in C++20.

Comment: The result should be false, a POD type should also be a trivial type. And trivial types must have a trivial default constructor, which you deleted. See [POD class, cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#POD_class) stating a POD class is a trivial class

Comment: cannot reproduce: [Live](https://godbolt.org/z/sbvqq5hPW).
both gcc and clang displays ```true```.
Yet I would agree with @PepijinKramer that the class is not POD due ti the deleted default constructor. Thus I'm confused by the output...

Comment: [POD class, cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#POD_class) wording is ambiguous: is a **POD class trivial _and_ standard layout** or **POD class trivial _or_ standard layout**. In the later case, the OP class is standard layout which might explain the output.

Comment: [C++ standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) section D.11: **A POD class is a class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout
class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD class (or array thereof).** Which settle my other comment and increases my confusion.

Comment: GCC seems to disagree on the result of std::is_trivial.
It says true, the others say false.

Comment: @JWellbelove can you post a godbolt link or equivalent?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/EdMsnq1oT

Oddly, clang on my machine (Windows) say false, Godbolt (assuming Linux) says true.

Comment: Your godbolt link is to GCC, not clang

Comment: Clang 15
https://godbolt.org/z/xdWKcnc3x

Comment: Clang 14 on Ubuntu 22.04 says true.