# Why does std::is_trivial work different in different compilers?

Tags: c++, private-constructor

Why does

```
class C {
private:
    C() = default;
};

static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<C>)
```

compile fine with gcc but not with msvc?

`error C2607: static assertion failed`

As show https://godbolt.org/z/e4Yo9KWo9

Comment: please include compiler errors in the question directly

Comment: You should mention that it's about the default constructor being `private` which causes this behaviour.

Comment: check what c++ version is used, different compilers use different defaults. For such comparisons best is to set it expliticlty

Comment: I think that there is a similar issue with ```std::is_POD```. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462589/which-is-the-correct-output-for-stdis-pod-for-this-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference Class Member Triviality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876410/reference-class-member-triviality)

Comment: MSVC [seems to use](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/9f9ab8855c9bb5ac68f462fa540ab565d25e34ff/stl/inc/type_traits#L695) `is_trivially_constructible` to resolve the requirement "has one or more eligible default constructors such that each is trivial". And the class *has* a default constructor, but it is still not default constructible.